# JW Player embedded flash player not playing properly

Tags: javascript, flash, jwplayer

PROBLEM: when i press play the audio starts but the video does not.

CODE:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

<title>JW Player for Flash</title>

</head><body>

<script type="text/javascript" src="swfobject.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    swfobject.registerObject("player","9.0.98","expressInstall.swf");
</script>

<object id="player" classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" name="player" width="468" height="262">
    <param name="movie" value="player-licensed.swf" />
    <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" />
    <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" />
    <param name="flashvars" value="file=Bioshphere-Museum-of-Water.flv&image=preview.jpg" />
    <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="player-licensed.swf" width="468" height="262">
        <param name="movie" value="player-licensed.swf" />
        <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" />
        <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" />
        <param name="flashvars" value="file=video.flv&image=preview.jpg" />
        <p><a href="http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer">Get Flash</a> to watch this video.</p>
    </object>
</object>
</body>
</html>
```

LIVE EXAMPLE: http://solomongiles.com/mediamar/readme.html

Solutions?

Answer (score 1):

Use the script found here, http://www.walkernews.net/2008/01/11/how-to-embed-flv-flash-in-wordpress-or-html/, with new player.  It works in IE.  I've also added allowfullscreen="true" allowsscriptaccess="always" after the size parameters.  Plays in IE but no full screen.  Help with this if you can please.

Answer (score 0):

Works fine here in mac/safari 4.0.3.

However I do notice one thing - your flashvars for the object and param bits don't match up. They should be the same.

Also, you make want to look into a more flexible embedding solution such as SWFObject (it helps you do player detection and will let your document validate as XHTML as well)

Comment: can you be more specific about the object and param bits not matching up?

Comment: also, it seems like the swf object is being called in the javascript, am i missing something?

Comment: Hmm, looking at it more, something seems really goofy there. Usually you have an object tag and an embed tag - you seem to have two object tags. The two object tags have different values set for the flashvars parameter. You really should look at SWFObject - yes, it does use javascript to do the embedding for you. You just create an empty div (well, it often contains a "you need to get flash" message) and then write a tiny bit of JS to populate that div with the proper embedding code. It's the easiest and most robust way of embedding Flash out there.

Answer (score 0):

```
<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,40,0" width="640" height="480"><param name="flashvars" value="file=http://www.webiste.com/admin/php_uploads/video.flv&image=imgs/image_large.jpg" /><param name="movie" value="flvplayer/player.swf" /><embed src="flvplayer/player.swf" width="640" height="480" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" flashvars="file=http://www.webiste.com/admin/php_uploads/video.flv&image=imgs/image_large.jpg" /></object>
```